# Do Chrome and IE have a "Text Zoom Only" mode as found in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, zoom

The "Text Zoom Only" mode is a neat feature in Firefox that ensures only text will be zoomed; images will remain the same size. This avoids making web pages looking awkward when zooming in.

Do Chrome and Internet Explorer have such option as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer has always had this functionality, called *Text Size*.
It's separate from the zoom function and only has 5 options, but is more or less what you are looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome [FontSizeIncrease](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ombpcpigmndepfckcifdblemkabaoihk) is an extension that allows you to increase the zoom for the text only.

Could not find any such accelerators for IE.

Comment: Thanks but what about such extension for Chrome and Explorer?